# ANOVA test: is it normal that if alpha is lower, we accept more often the hypothesis H0?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova

Let's say we do an ANOVA to test the hypothesis H0: $µ_1 = µ_2 = µ_3$, with the following data (each row is for one of the *three* classes):

[image]

We have:

[image]

- If we take the classical value $\alpha = 0.05$, then the threshold (computed with F distribution) is $F_0 = 4.2565$. Since $F > F_0$, **we reject H0**.
- If we take the value $\alpha = 0.01$, then the threshold (computed with F distribution) is $F_0 = 8.0215$. Since $F < F_0$, **we do not reject H0**.

How can we explain that "H0 is rejected when $1-\alpha$ is 95%", but "H0 is accepted when $1-\alpha$ is 99%", doesn't this seem counterintuitive?

We accept H0 when using 99% (intuitively, in this case, it should be more difficult to pass the test) but not with 95%, is this counterintuitive?

Comment: $95$ and $99\%$ confidence of what?

Comment: Your conclusions about rejecting or not rejecting H0 are backward.  You do reject with alpha=0.05 but not with alpha=0.01

Comment: @HarveyMotulsky It is the exactly the conclusions I wrote, didn't I? Maybe did I miswrite it? Anyway, I edited to make it clearer.

Comment: @Dave What do you think about the new formulation?

Comment: @Basj I repeat my question from a few hours ago: confidence of what? Sure, you dropped the word from your question, but you’re still alluding to some kind of confidence level.

Comment: @Dave I mean the statistical significance at the 0.05 or 0.01 alpha level.

Answer (score 1):

When $\alpha=0.05,$ we would reject when $p\in[0,0.05].$

When $\alpha=0.01,$ we would reject when $p\in[0,0.01].$

The second condition is more restrictive. Every rejection under $\alpha=0.01$ would have occurred for $\alpha=0.05,$ but the reverse is false. For instance, $p=0.03$ means rejection at $\alpha=0.05$ but not at $\alpha=0.01$. Therefore, yes, lower $\alpha$ means fewer rejections of the null hypothesis.

This kind of dichotomous thinking can be problematic, but a strict Neyman-Pearson approach to hypothesis testing works this way.

Finally, we don’t accept null hypotheses. We only fail to reject them. This is a subtle but important distinction, the details of which warrant a separate question that must already exist on Cross Validated (though I don’t offhand know where).